# Drawing/coloring application - flood fill algorithm/clipping region

Tags: java, android, image-processing, java-2d, flood-fill

I have to develop a coloring application. Basically the user is presented with an image. An outline of a character maybe and the user can fill it using different colors. I've looked at a few options but I can't seem to find a good one.

Could someone tell me how to fill the bitmap image.

Is there any sample code I can use? or an open source project?

It has to be done in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for some good Java Image processing Libraries like the ones listed here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4078479/what-android-3rd-party-libraries-are-there . Its not an Android question but more about Image processing

Answer (score 0):

The [Wikipedia entry on Flood Fill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) has the classical algorithm in pseudo-code, a few variants and optimizations and links to source code in several languages.